# Append data to table from json when headers are a mix of the keys and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, html-table

I have an array of objects, I want to add that data to an HTML table but I am having trouble appending it to the table as my table structure is slightly unique.

My headers are a mix of the keys and values and I want to be able to get their corresponding value to populate my cells.

My code:

```js
let data = [{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"Phone",vendor:"Apple",value:11},{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"Phone",vendor:"Google",value:10},{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"Tablet",vendor:"Apple",value:45},{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"Tablet",vendor:"Google",value:57},{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"iOT",vendor:"Apple",value:33},{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"iOT",vendor:"Google",value:11},{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"Smart Watch",vendor:"Apple",value:17},{Date:"2021-03-22",device:"Smart Watch",vendor:"Google",value:25},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"Phone",vendor:"Apple",value:9},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"Phone",vendor:"Google",value:20},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"Tablet",vendor:"Apple",value:23},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"Tablet",vendor:"Google",value:15},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"iOT",vendor:"Apple",value:11},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"iOT",vendor:"Google",value:77},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"Smart Watch",vendor:"Apple",value:38},{Date:"2021-03-29",device:"Smart Watch",vendor:"Google",value:80}];

let ths = ['device', 'vendor', '2021-03-22', '2021-03-29'];
ths.forEach(d => $(`#ths`).append(`<th id='${d}'>${d}</th>`));

data.forEach(d => {
  $(`#table_body`).append(`<tr class='my_rows'></tr>`);
  ['device', 'vendor'].forEach(x => $(`#table_body > tr:last`).append(`<td>${d[x]}</td>`));
  ['value'].forEach(y => {
    $(`.my_rows:last`).append(`<td>${d[y]}</td>`);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#mytable {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='mytable'>
  <thead>
    <tr id='ths'></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='table_body'></tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, my table is populating vertically and adding any data to `2021-03-29` and instead of adding all the data to the first date column.

How do I make my data look like:

| device | vendor | 2021-03-22 | 2021-03-29 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phone | Apple | 11 | 10 |
| Phone | Google | 45 | 57 |
| Tablet | Apple | 33 | 11 |
| Tablet | Google | 17 | 25 |
| iOt | Apple | 9 | 20 |
| iOt | Google | 23 | 15 |
| Smart Watch | Apple | 11 | 77 |
| Smart Watch | Google | 38 | 80 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, basically what I would do is transform the data that you have to a something simplier, so we can move from:

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "Phone",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "Phone",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 9
  },
  ....
]
```

to something like this:

```
[
  {
    "2021-03-22": "11",
    "2021-03-29": "9",
    "device": "Phone",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 11
  }
  ....
]
```

this can be achieved using `reduce` and convert it into and object and the with `Object.values()` we can get the array transformed.

here you have the working solution using the same renderer of the table.
notice that I merged both items into one, using the `date` as a key and the `value` will be the value of that date.

```js
let data = [{
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "Phone",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "Phone",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "Tablet",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 45
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "Tablet",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 57
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "iOT",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 33
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "iOT",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "Smart Watch",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-22",
    "device": "Smart Watch",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "Phone",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 9
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "Phone",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "Tablet",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 23
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "Tablet",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 15
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "iOT",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "iOT",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 77
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "Smart Watch",
    "vendor": "Apple",
    "value": 38
  },
  {
    "Date": "2021-03-29",
    "device": "Smart Watch",
    "vendor": "Google",
    "value": 80
  }
];

let ths = ['device', 'vendor', '2021-03-22', '2021-03-29'];
ths.forEach(d => $(`#ths`).append(`<th id='${d}'>${d}</th>`));


const reducer = (accum, cv) => {
  const key = cv.vendor + cv.device;
  // if there isnt an entry we create a new one.
  if (!accum[key]) {
    accum[key] = {
      device: cv.device,
      vendor: cv.vendor,
      [cv.Date]: cv.value
    };
  } else {
    // we have an entry we just add the value for the date.
    accum[key][cv.Date] = cv.value
  }

  return accum;


}

const obj = data.reduce(reducer, {});
const newForm = Object.values(obj);

newForm.forEach(d => {
  $(`#table_body`).append(`<tr class='my_rows'></tr>`);
  ['device', 'vendor'].forEach(x => $(`#table_body > tr:last`).append(`<td>${d[x]}</td>`));
  ['2021-03-22', '2021-03-29'].forEach(y => {
    $(`.my_rows:last`).append(`<td>${d[y]}</td>`);
  });
})
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#mytable {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='mytable'>
  <thead>
    <tr id='ths'></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='table_body'></tbody>
</table>
```